# markdown(md) file viewer in ASP.NET Core

Tags: typescript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to create a ASP.NET core web application which can show markdown file to user in bowser. Applicaiton will get the content/md file from blob storage account and have to show content to user.

Is this possible to do in ASP.NET core Or is there any other javascript framework that can be used along with ASP.NET core to implement this functionality.
the content can be multiple file(link), so when user click on link from first file, second file should load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could use [marked](https://marked.js.org/) js library to achieve your requirement. You could write the logic inside the controller to get the md file content and then pass it to the view and use the marked library to show it.

Also you could use ajax to get the content from controller by using azure blob library inside the backend and then render it by using the marked library.

Below is a small sample:

View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MarkDownContent";
}

@model string 

<h1>MarkDownContent</h1>

<div id="markdown-container">
 </div>

 @section Scripts{

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Render Markdown content using Marked.js
        document.getElementById('markdown-container').innerHTML = marked.parse('@Model');


    </script>

 }
```

Controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> MarkDownContent()
    { 

        //You should write the codes to get the content from the blob by yourself. 
        string content = $@"# Marked in browser\n\nRendered by **marked**.";

        return View("MarkDownContent", content);
    }
```

Result:

[image]